# How to use if condition in for loop ? Jinja

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, flask, jinja2

I have two list and one variable returned from the Flask page to my HTML page.

`a = [11121,11122,11123,11124,11130]
b = [11126,11127,11128,11129,11130]
var = 11121`

In python code :

`if var in a:
    print("comes in a")
elif var in b:
    print("comes in b")
else:
    print("comes in both")`

But I figured out that we need to iterate list first in jinja. (may be I'am wrong)

Now I want to check if var either comes in a, or in b or in both in jinja2.

Comment: In which form you "want to check"? You'd like to get two booleans like `comes_from_a` and `comes_from_b`? Or something else?

Comment: I have updated the question.Kindly check.

Comment: So, it means I understood you correctly. :) See the answer. Spoiler: you can use `in` in Jinja2 in the same way as in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you don't need `for` loop for it. You can check it with `in` tester. Like this:

```
{{ "comes from a" if var in a }}
{{ "comes from b" if var in b }}
```

`if var in a` (or `if var in b`) check the existence of `var` in `a` (or `b`) arrays of values. It's a form of expression so you can freely use it in the expression context. For instance, you can assign result of checking to the variable:

```
{% set comes_from_a = var in a %}
{% set comes_from_b = var in b %}
```

Comment: I used {{ "comes from a" if var in a }}
{{ "comes from b" if var in b }} in my code, but it's not working when its actually present in the list. :(

Comment: I suppose, it should works perfectly if `var` has the same type as items in list. I checked both samples for the json dataset:

    { 
    "a": [11121,11122,11123,11124,11130],
    "b": [11126,11127,11128,11129,11130],
    "var": 11121
    }

and got the expected result.

Comment: render_template('index.html',var = idnum, a = freq_table, b = ds_table) This is how I'm passing values from Flask to the index.html page.

Comment: What is the result of applying of `pprint` filter to the `var`, `a` and `b`? For instance, what does `{{ a | pprint }}` produce?

Comment: '11161'
[11115, 11120, 11124, 11125, 11130]
[11111, 11120, 11125, 11130, 11131, 11132, 11132, 11134, 11135, 11137, 11140, 11142, 11143, 11145, 11146, 11147, 11150, 11151, 11153, 11154, 11155, 11156, 11157, 11158, 11160, 11161]

This is what the output of {{ var |pprint }}{{ a |pprint }}{{ b |pprint }}

Comment: Looks like card ID (`var`) is a string, but array contains integers. So, try to apply `| int` to `var` before checking the existence.

Comment: Applying | int in the condition solved my issue. Thank you so much :))

Comment: By the way, is it possible to print  "comes from a" or "comes from b" in <h1> tag ???

Comment: I suppose, yes. What the exact problem with it?

Comment: When I wrote <h1>Comes in a {{ if var |int in a}}</h1> I got this error., jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'var'

Comment: When you use `if` as an expression (like in your snippet) you should prepend it with something evaluable _inside_ braces. I.e. in your case you should write:  `<h1>{{ "Comes in a" if var |int in a}}</h1>` It means 'print "Comes in a" if a contains var'. Or you can surround the whole header with `if` tag: `{% if var | int in a %}<h1>Comes in a</h1>{% endif %}`

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. You are so nice :))